# How to make formula field return type as email

Tags: formula-field

In our application we are using gmail button and links,which helps to get gmail button linked with all email type fields.

But we have formula field which will return the email as text type.Which makes ups to run into problems--- we cannot get that gmail button links for this text field.So i was wondering is there any way to get return type of the formula field as email type... or any other ways to achieve this...

un fortunately google doesn't helps me much on this ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with a formula field.

An alternative might be to use a workflow with a field update to update an Email field with the same formula.

Maybe also look into a product like Cirrus Insight which provides pretty nice integration with Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
HYPERLINK("mailto:email@email.com","Click here for email")
```

If you create a formula as a Text type and then put the above in you will be good to go.

[See SF page here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK)